# UIScrollView won't scroll inside as subview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIViewController and a UIScrollView. Since I have to add multiple views to the view controller, and the scroll view is just one of them, I tried to set the view of the controller to an dummy UIView and the scroll as child, like this:

```
    [self setView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]];
    [[self view] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    // TDHexMapScrollView inherits from UIViewController
    [self setHexMapScrollView:[[TDHexMapScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self hexMapScrollView]];
```

This way the scrolling doesn't work. Adding it as the main view makes scrolling and panning work correctly:

```
    [self setHexMapScrollView:[[TDHexMapScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]];
    [self setView:[self hexMapScrollView]];
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Check that both have userInteractionEnabled=YES

Comment: have you tried setting the `contentInset`

Comment: Is the scrollView encompassing all the other views? Or are you only trying to scroll a certain subset? I've done both multiple times, but my first guess as to what you might be missing is `[TDHexMapScrollView setContentSize:size of the views to be scrolled];`

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
[[self view] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

That disables interaction for the view and all subviews. That means it ignores touch events and does not propagate them to its subviews, which means your scrollview doesn't get any events.

Comment: i added it afterward as one of the tries. setting it to yes or no doesn't change the non-working behavior

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get reply on my comment, but I figured I would show you an example of how I go about doing this.

Declare

```
CGSize scrollSize;
```

In your implementation. Then create your scrollView, views, labels, etc.

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenFrame.size.width, screenFrame.size.height - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollSize.height = self.View1.frame.size.height + self.Label1.frame.size.height + self.Label2.frame.size.height + self.Label3.frame.size.height + self.Label4.frame.size.height + self.Label5.frame.size.height + self.Label6.frame.size.height;
scrollSize.width = screenFrame.size.width;
[self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollSize];
```

Add to the scrollView

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.View1];
//Repeat for all views / labels / etc
```

Add the scrollView to the ViewController

```
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```